# Cannot send email with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp, smtpclient

My Project need to send an e-mail but I cannot send it. I don't know why. Last month I can send but today I cannot.

```
string url = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
string hyperlink = "<a href='" + url + "'>" + url + "</a>";
NetworkCredential loginInfo = new NetworkCredential("***examplemail***", "myPassword");
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.From = new MailAddress("***examplemail***");
msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("***ToEmail***"));
msg.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress("***examplemail***"));
msg.Subject = "TEST";
msg.Body = "Hi, TEST Send E-mail";
msg.IsBodyHtml = false;
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 995); // tried 25 587 and 995
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = loginInfo;
client.Send(msg);
```

** It didn't have any error but I didn't send too.

Comment: If you try 995, it **will** give you an error.  Check your `catch` blocks.

Comment: can you wrap this code around a try{}catch{} `client.Send(msg);` and report back what the exception is.. perhaps there is an exception happening but it's just now being thrown..

Comment: I got "Failure sending mail. "

Comment: I just tried port 25 and 587 and got the same error.

Comment: Here is another similar question that might help you out.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use the port number in here.

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 995); // tried 25 587 and 995
```

This way it sends. I tried and it worked. I am saying that it should look like

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
```

If you check SmtpClient's constructor while writing the code you will see that it has one overload.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace consSendMail
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                Port = 587,
                EnableSsl = true,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("yourmail", "yourpassword")
            };

            var mailMessage = new MailMessage();
            mailMessage.Subject = "Subject";
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("yourmail", "yourname");
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mailMessage.Body = "your message";            
            mailMessage.To.Add( new MailAddress("destinationemail") );

            smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);

            mailMessage.Dispose();
            smtpClient.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Both the `SmtpClient` and the `MailMessage` need to be in `using` blocks.

Comment: I have been tested this. It works. Now I have been edited this to complete example program.

Comment: And they should still be in `using` blocks to ensure they are cleaned up promptly, even in the case of an exception.